# ecryptfs on raspbmc

Tags: raspbmc

Trying to get ecryptsfs on a RaspBMC install and having trouble.

Reason:  Ideally want single RPi to perform both as a media center and backing up another NAS (Synology via NFS) to encrypted external USB (only want some of the folders encrypted)

Tried following this good guide but cannot seem to get it working.
http://www.development-cycle.com/2013/12/encypting-diectories-with-ecryptfs/

Seems like there is no kernel module available.  What am I missing?

```
//raspbmc build/version
pi@raspbmc:~$ cat /scripts/upd_hist/build_info
raspbmc-rls-1.0-hardfp-b20140527-u20140527

//check ecryptfs is installed
pi@raspbmc:~$ sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ecryptfs-utils is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 26 not upgraded.

//check for module
pi@raspbmc:~$ lsmod | grep ecryptfs
pi@raspbmc:~$

//check for module to load
pi@raspbmc:~$ cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)
pi@raspbmc:/lib/modules/3.12.21$ ls kernel/fs/
9p              cifs      gfs2     isofs  nilfs2  ocfs2     squashfs
binfmt_misc.ko  exportfs  hfs      jfs    nls     quota     udf 
btrfs           fuse      hfsplus  nfsd   ntfs    reiserfs  xfs
```